# Square an array's size with the same pattern repeated

Tags: c++, arrays

Given an array `int X[x_size]`, I'd like to make a new array `int Y[x_size * x_size]` and copy the values of `X` in order.

For example, given `X = {0, 1, 2}`, I'd like array `Y` to be `{0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2}`.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int x[3] = [0,1,2];
    int * y = makeY(a,3);
}
int * makeY(int x[], int size) {
    int *y = new int[size * size];
    for(int i = 0; i < size; size+=2)
        for(int j = i; j < j + (size - 1); j++)
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                y[j+i] = x[i];
    return y;
}
```

Comment: "Y be double the size" size(X) = 3 and size(Y) = 9. Something's wrong, please check your example or your description.

Comment: I'm going to guess that you mean to square the size, not double it, but `size+=2` thing still looks weird

Comment: Is there a question you have? Is something not working? You need to be more specific

Comment: @m.k please accept an answer if it helped you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to work with pointers, I suggest passing the pointer of y instead of returning it since it is a local variable.

```
void makeY(int * x, int * y, int size){     
     for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
      for(int j = 0; j < (size); j++){
       y[j*size + i] = x[i];
      }
     }     
}
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
int main()
{
  int size = 3;
  int x[size] = {0, 1, 2};
  int y[size * size];
  makeY(x, y, size);
}
```

Comment: VLAs are non-standard.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you're allowed to have fun with the standard library:

```
std::vector<int> repeat_square_vector(const std::vector<int>& original)
{
    std::vector<int> repeated(original.size() * original.size());
    std::generate(repeated.begin(), repeated.end(), [&original](){static size_t i = 0; return original[i++ % original.size()];});
    return repeated;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> original = {0, 1, 2};
    std::vector<int> repeated = repeat_square_vector(original);
    //repeated == {0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2}
}
```

Comment: Can you provide also the main function so I can see how your approach is used, please?

Comment: @m.k I added a sample main.

Answer (score -1):

I am adding in a generalized logic:

```
y_size=x_size*x_size;
i=0;
for(j=0;j<y_size;j++)
{
   if (i<x_size)
   {
        y[j]=x[i++];
    }
    else
    {
        i=0;
        y[j]=x[i++];
    }
}
```